# How to see file permissions and ownership in git bash (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, git-bash, ownership

When I do `ls -l`, all files appear to have the same user, and all appear to have same permissions:

- regular files have `-rw-r--r--`
- executables have `-rwxr-xr-x`
- directories have `drwxr-xr-x`

Regardless of who actually owns them.

If I use my admin privileges, and check directories that belong to other users, ownership and permission look exactly the same.

How can I see and change permission and ownership within git bash?

Comment: Did you run "git ls-files --stage" to check the file permission? I think you can read this thread [Git file permissions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476513/git-file-permissions-on-windows). There are some discussions might help you.

Answer (score 0):

to see the ownership and permission of a file or folder use this command

`ls -la folder_name/file_name`

result

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121 0 Oct 27 01:19 ../folder (if it is folder)
rwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121   28 Nov 30 23:14 file  (if it is file)
```

to change the permission of folder and file use this

- `chmod 765 folder_name/or file_name`

the first "7" is for user, the second "6" is for group, and the third "5" is for others

or you can use the following command

- `chmod u+x folder_name/file_name` (to give excute access for user)
- `chmod g+x folder_name/file_name` (to give excute access for group )
- `chmod o+x folder_name/file_name` (to give excute access for other)
- `chmod ugo+rwx folder_name/file_name` (to give r=read,w=write,x=execute
  access for user,group and other )

Answer (score -1):

Try `ls -al` to include ownership

Comment: `-a` just shows hidden files. And I'm already using `-l`